# jquery check for checked input

Tags: jquery, if-statement, insert, attr, remove-if

I have few radio inputs with unique id's. Now i have a script that shows some extra content if one of them is checked. It works. But i want to clear that extra content when i check another radio input. 
This code don't work is i thought. It is not clearing that extra content.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#delivery_option_5_1").change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(".delivery_options").after("<p id='extracontent'>Hello!</p>");
        }
        else {
            $("#extracontent").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your HTML.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle.

Comment: You should be using `if ( this.checked ) { ...`, the attribute will never change when you check the box.

Comment: you can use `if ($(this).is(":checked")){`

Comment: My html doesn't matter because i need to do this without editing anything in html, html is generated by prestashop.

Comment: @MohitArora ok but im kinda newbie. How can i select all other radio inputs except that one that triggers $(".delivery_options").after() function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like that.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wpunkcie").change(function () {

        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("#wysylka").after("<p id='info'>Mapa i informacja o wysyłce</p>");
        }
    });
    $("#inne").change(function () {



        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("#info").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="wysylka"><input type="radio" name="halo" id="wpunkcie"> Odbiór w punkcie pocztowym</input><br>
    <input type="radio" name="halo" id="inne">Inna forma wysyłki</input></form>
```

Thx for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just always delete it before you add a new one. Also use `prop` instead of `attr`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#delivery_option_5_1").change(function () {

        $("#extracontent").remove();

        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $(".delivery_options").after("<p id='extracontent'>Hello!</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but still nothing. Only improvement is taht script isn't adding another #extracontent elements when i check another radio and chceck #delivery_option_5_1 again but it's not removing that #extracontent when i check other radio input.

Comment: Do you only want to add the extra content div on `#delivery_option_5_1`? Also is the div `delivery_options` right after the `#delivery_option_5_1` checkbox? Can you maybe add the html to your question?